# Electron ReferenceError __dirname is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

whenever I try to

```js
import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';
```

from the renderer, I get a ReferenceError (__dirname is not defined).

I'm using the [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) and I did't modify any of the code except for React-components in the renderer.